# Why Magical Law Enforcement are completely idiotic in terms of proving/disproving someone's guilt?

Tags: harry-potter

So, basically what do we have:

- Imperius curse
- Terror tactics
- Legillemency / Occlumency
- Veritaserum
- Cruciatus curse
- Memory extraction spells + Pensieves
- Obliviation
- Confundus
- Priori Incantatem

How the hell do you prove/disprove anyone's guilt? Or an even better question - why didn't Wizengamot's triggerhappies actually use all (or a combination) of the above-mentioned tools to extract the truth from the people they judged? I'm not suggesting that everything should start with a good-ol Crucio - we can always begin with something less powerful and dangerous - a Confundus could literally make a person confused and spill the beans. Memory extraction isn't considered harmful too.

The following cases are illustrative for my point:

- How come did Sirius Black end up in jail, when it was soooooo damn easy to check his story;
- How did Lucius Malfoy sell his story about being under Imperius;
- How did Pettigrew and other traitors conceal their allegiance;
- How did Death Eaters conceal their identities from Aurors and Order of Phoenix (who were actual bloody vigilantes and didn't care about laws and stuff as much), when Aurors had a right to use the unforgivable curses. I can easily imagine Mad-Eye doing something along the following: "Imperio. Now tell me everything. Thank you, Avada Kedavra".

Comment: This is (1) too broad - too many questions; (2) some are already answered on this site, did you check?

Comment: Because memories can be tampered with, with trivial ease. A skilled magician could therefore get away with murder over and over again in your world.

Comment: So, basically, you're saying there is no reliable way to know what really occurred but to believe the "he did that" logic. That is, to my mind, a mistake. For instance mass tampering with memories is at least time consuming - wizards could've checked muggle witnesses to Black's "crime" with proper magical means to ensure the truth.

Comment: What I am trying to say is - wizards have A LOT of powerful techniques to get creative in their investigations. They did not do that. Why, when the odds are sending a known ally and a fellow man to dementors for the crime he did not commit?

Comment: DVK, I'm asking only "why didn't Wizengamot's triggerhappies actually use all (or a combination) of the above-mentioned tools to extract the truth from the people they judged?". Other questions are for the purpose of illustrating my point.

Comment: @DVK The questions posed at the end are rhetorical. *There are many cases where that sort of question should've been asked in the story:*

Comment: I suggest re-writing your other examples as statements instead of questions. While you may not mean for them to be additional questions, it currently reads as such.

Comment: Moody saying to a Death Eater,_"Imperio. Now tell me everything. Thank you, Avada Kedavra"_  can easily happen the other way round.

Comment: and it actually did, I suppose

Comment: @Vorren - "why"? Because they had no particular incentive to bother. Thise duplicate questions I alluded to explain that. Why would they waste time finding THE truth when they don't really need to?

Comment: removing the formatting isn't at all the same as rewriting the questions into statements

Comment: Isn't this sort of what Lord Darcy deals with?